# Pandas Columns Division by a Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which has 29 columns like following:

[image]

Also, I have a folder which contains a bunch of images.

This csv contains header and ground truth points for every image in images folder. It has 29 columns. First column is a filename and next 28 columns are x and y coordinates for 14 facepoints.

My code:

```
def load_imgs_and_keypoints(dirname='facial-keypoints', image_size=(100, 100)):

  images = []
  points = []
  base_path = '/content/facial-keypoints/data/images'

  # Get all the images
  for file in os.listdir(base_path):

    # Set the path and read the image
    full_img_path = os.path.join(base_path, file)
    image = cv2.imread(full_img_path)

    # Get the rows and cols of image
    rows = image.shape[0]
    cols = image.shape[1]
    channels = image.shape[2]

    rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    rgb_image = cv2.resize(rgb_image, image_size)
    images.append(rgb_image)

  # Read the csv file which contains facial keypoints
  csv_path = '/content/facial-keypoints/data/gt.csv'
  csv_file = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
  print(csv_file.head())

  print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')

  # Scale the coordinates
  all_X_cols = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 
                'x11', 'x12', 'x13','x14']

  all_Y_cols = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5', 'y6', 'y7', 'y8', 'y9', 'y10', 
                'y11', 'y12', 'y13','y14']
```

What I want to do is -

Divide all x's by number of columns of image (cols), and divide all y's by number of rows of image (rows) and subtract 0.5 from all values.

I was not sure how to get all the X's and Y's from the csv and do the needful.

How can I achieve this task?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is relatively simple. Essentially, you just loop through the columns and apply the operation you want to each column. For performing the operation, you don't need any special functions. You can just write it as a vectorized operation that treat your series like a vector and that can be divided/subtracted by a scalar. You can change the way that you're counting the columns if you want to include the filename column.

```
all_X_cols = [i for i in csv_file.columns if "x" in i]
all_Y_cols = [i for i in csv_file.columns if "y" in i]

num_cols = len([i for i in csv_file.columns if i != "filename"])
num_rows = len(sv_file)

for x in all_X_cols:
    csv_file[x] = (csv_file[x]/num_cols)-.5

for y in all_Y_cols:
    csv_file[y] = (csv_file[y]/num_rows)-.5
```

Comment: This was simple. But isn't it tedious to make a list of all the columns? I just wanted to know whether there is a solution in which I wouldn't have to make a list of columns.

Comment: I edited the solution to include your question. The method I use and am showing here works if you can guarantee consistent naming of columns. In this case, we know that we can separate the columns based on whether there is an 'x' or 'y' in the name. Now you don't have to copy/paste and can have additional x/y columns without needing to alter your code.

Comment: Apologies, I think I misunderstood your question at first. I thought you were asking how to get the actual X and Y columns for the operations, not how to get the labels for those columns.

Comment: No worries, This solution worked quite well. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if (col[0]=='x'):
        df[col] = np.where(df['filename'] == file, df[col] / cols, df[col])
    else:
        df[col] = np.where(df['filename'] == file, df[col] / rows, df[col])
```

Comment: Yes. You need to replace "df" with the name of your dataframe